# Организация CSS классов на примере?

Tags: html, css, инспекция-кода, бэм

Имеется html верстка, хочу понять на наглядном примере, как сейчас пишут названия классов.

Рекомендовали использовать BEM формат. Изучил, написал классы, но есть чувство, что делаю что-то не так, т.к. в финальное версии класса получилось что-то вроде:

```
.header__contacts-1__list__phone__code {}
.header__contacts-1__list__phone__number {}
```

Не слишком длинное название класса, и может нет необходимости использовать в нем все дочерние классы?

Чтобы мне было проще понять, написал часть шапки. Подскажите, как Вы писали-бы классы на примере подобной верстки? Необязательно BEM, просто Ваш метод грамотного написания/организации классов.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <a href="/">
                    <img src="logo.png">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span>(495)</span>
                        <span>123-45-67</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>(495)</span>
                        <span>123-45-67</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу предложить следующее наименование классов (по методологии БЭМ):

```css
//стили логотипа, как отдельного компонента
.logo {}
.logo img {}

//стили телефона, как отдельного компонента
.phone {}
.phone__code {}
.phone__number {}

//стили шапки
.header {}

//дополнительные стили логотипа как компонента шапки
.header__logo {}

//стили меню навигации
.nav {}
.nav-list {}
.nav-list__item {}

//дополнительные стили телефона, как компонента меню навигации
.nav-list__phone {}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="/" class="logo header__logo">
    <img src="logo.png">
  </a>

  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="phone nav-list__item nav-list__phone">
        <span class="phone__code">(495)</span>
        <span class="phone__number">123-45-67</span>
      </li>
      <li class="phone nav-list__item nav-list__phone">
        <span class="phone__code">(495)</span>
        <span class="phone__number">123-45-67</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Используя методологию БЭМ вы должны ориентироваться на то, чтобы блоки были именованы таким образом, чтобы их можно было переиспользовать.

В данном случае, вы отдельно задаете стили для компонента логотипа и для компонента телефона, а затем, в нужных блоках просто примиксовываете стили тех блоков, в которых эти компоненты размещаются.

Подробнее про миксы можете почитать в [разделе документации про миксы](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/block-modification/#%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Comment: А если данный блок шапки не один на сайте, а есть еще блоки, например еще один телефон уже в подвале и у него тоже будут классы `.phone {} .phone__code {} .phone__number {}` , как тогда отделять одни одинаковые классы от других? Писать `.header .phone {}` ?

Comment: Я добавил описание в ответе, предлагаю вам использовать миксы)) Т.е. для конкретного блока вы можете добавлять стили для телефона, подходящие конкретному блоку. Сами компоненты не должны влиять на внешнее окружение.

Comment: Прочитал, не понятен вопрос, как именно писать классы в css файле. Например нам нужно стилизовать блок телефона, который лежит в шапке, нужно указывать к нему такой путь `.header .phone` ?, ну или если нужно стилизовать код телефона, то `.header .phone__code` ?

Comment: Если вам нужно стилизовать блок телефона так, чтобы указать что он лежит в шапке, то к классу `.phone` добавляете класс `.header-phone` - т.е. вы таким образом создаете блок, который будет лежать именно в шапке. Затем для дочерних элементов вы указываете (если это необходимо) классы `.header-phone__code` и `.header-phone__number`, при этом, вам не придется писать длинные классы)) Миксовать можно как элементы так и блоки.

Answer (score 2):

По методологии БЭМ у вас не должно получаться таких длинных селекторов. У вас сейчас получается Блок-Элемент-Элемент-Элемент и т.д., а должно быть Блок Элемент. На самом деле в [спецификации](https://ru.bem.info/) всё довольно-таки подробно описано. В Вашем примере,я вижу примерно следующие селекторы:

`.header`, `.header__logo`, `header__phones`, `phones__item`.

А спаны, в которые соответственно заключены код и номер телефона будут уже модификаторами,если у них разные цвета/размеры шрифтов и т.п., например:

`.phones__item_red`, `.phones__item_small`

Comment: Очень интересно, благодарю!